# ObjectContext DeleteObject

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

Below is my working table.

```
OrderID  ProductID UnitPrice
1        P001      10
1        P002      11
1        P003      12
2        P001      10
```

I use below code to make delete every row(s) which orderID is 1.

```
void DeleteOrderMaster(int OrderID)
{ 
        Order _Order = DB.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderID == OrderID);
        DB.Orders.DeleteObject(_Order);
}
```

What my problem is about ...

```
ObjectContext.Table.DeleteObject(entity);
```

As I am not very familiar with DeleteObject function, I want to call that function like that

```
DeleteOrderMaster(1)
```

Please let me know is this correct way or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Order _Order = DB.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderID == OrderID);
 db.Orders.DeleteObject(_Order);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Remove is a method of DbSet class which can only be created from a DbContext class which is a part of Entity Framework.

**EDIT**

May be I confused myself, which as a result confused you. First of all apologies for that.

Now, coming back to explanation, you are indeed using the Entity Framework. The ObjectContext Class you mentioned and the DbContext class i referred both are parts of the Entity framework itself. The ObjectContext class lives in **System.Data.Objects** namespace whereas DbContext lives in the **System.Data.Entity** namespace.

*Both ObjectContext and DbContext* class provides facilities for querying and working with entity data as objects.

**Now, When to use which one** :-

Use ObjectContext for version 4.0 when using a designer generated model and DbContext with a 4.1 Code First model. Since you are using designer, I would say you go with ObjectContext.

Once again aplologies for the confusion. Hope, now I have given a better and complete answer

Comment: I think , may be you have good reason why I should use Remove function

Comment: I think Remove function only support for those who use DataContext, but not for those who use ObjectContext. Am i correct ?

Comment: I use System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext and .edmx file to interact with database

Comment: hmm....dats why you need to use @AVD answer. Object Context doesn't have Remove() method. You simplly need to use `db.Orders.DeleteObject(_order)` and then call `db.SaveChanges()`

Comment: but I don't think that the way I using is not Entity Framework way.

Comment: according to your message that say "I suppose you are not using Entity Framework".

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can read the improved and corrected answer

Comment: I really appreciate your complete answer and thank you again @Pankaj Upadhyay

Answer (score 3):

[ObjectContext.DeleteObject(object entity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.deleteobject.aspx) method delete any entity that is not in *detached* state (object context is not set).

```
void DeleteOrderMaster(int OrderID)
{ 
        Order _Order = DB.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrderID == OrderID);
       if(_Order!=null)
         DB.DeleteObject(_Order);
}
```